# Back and forth navigation

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Is it somehow possible to show specific ViewController? I want to navigate back and forth to preserve page specific scroll etc. I tried set up stack with setPages(). I am able to getViews(). So I wondered that I can modify the stack with something like:

```
var head = views.shift();
views.push(head);
setViews(views);
```

The obvious problem is that I set views instead of pages. And when I map views to pages the information about scroll is lost. For me the best would be to be able to pop view and add it as tail and push tail as head into navigation stack, but I didn't find any possibility how to do it. And show(view). Any suggestion?